# Android app fails to load Youtube video on Android 12, but works on Android 8

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have developed an Android application in native Android that is supposed to load a YouTube video. Surprisingly, it works perfectly fine on Android 8.1 (Oreo), but fails to load the video on Android 12. I'm wondering why this discrepancy exists and what could be causing the issue.

One interesting observation is that when I download the APK directly and install it, the app functions properly and is able to load YouTube videos on both Android 8.1 and Android 12. However, when I download the app from the Google Play Store, the video loading feature fails on Android 12, while still working on Android 8.1.

Are there any known compatibility issues between native Android development and Android 12 when it comes to loading YouTube videos in apps downloaded from the Google Play Store? Has anyone else encountered a similar problem and found a solution?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

I have checked my code and verified that it is correctly implemented to load the YouTube video.The necessary permissions for internet access and video playback are included in the app's manifest file.

Comment: share the play store link